# Looking for famous scientist who originated the quote: "keep ten problems in your mind.."

Tags: quote-source

I have a vague recollection of a scientist sharing a problem solving strategy. The content of that quote or strategy, which I do not recollect literally, can be summarized as:

> Keep a list of 10 unsolved problems (that you would like to solve) in
> your head, and every time a mathematician/physicist comes up with a
> new solution to some problem, take that solution and try to see if you
> can apply it to any of the problems in the list.

I think it was Robbert Dijkgraaf telling that Robert Oppenheimer said something to this extent, but I cannot seem to find the quote or fragment.

Does anyone know who gave this quote or strategy?